# Rounding the quotient of a division?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rounding

I'm trying to divide two columns in the select statement, then round the quotient to 4 decimal places.

```
select round(round(sum(case when acct_no = '2999' 
      and date between '1/1/14' and current_date then amount end)::numeric, 4)::float
 / round(sum(case when acct_no = '3989' 
      and date between '1/1/14' and current_date then amount end)::numeric, 4)::numeric, 4) column
from table
```

The rest of the query will hold multiple dates, so the dates in there should be necessary.

The error it is giving:

> ERROR: function round(double precision, integer) does not exist

This was attempted in PostgreSQL.

Comment: that looks like it should work!  did you try casting instead of ::numeric, like: cast(... as numeric) ?  Also, you could try coalescing the 'amount' to 0 or something (in case its coming back null) (e.g. coalesce(amount,0::expectedtype) )

Comment: As of right now it is working, but the only problem is that it isn't rounding it. It still has 14 numbers after the decimal.

Comment: That's because the round needs to occur after the division. not on the individual numerator and denominators. `round(round(sum(case when acct_no = '2999' and date between '1/1/14' and current_date then amount end)::numeric, 4)::float
 / round(sum(case when acct_no = '3989' 
      and date between '1/1/14' and current_date then amount end)::numeric, 4)::Numeric,4)` I think In essence your saying round 22.0000 to 4 then 7.000 to 4 then divide the two giving...3.1428571... but don't round it.

Comment: oh, i didn't realize the problem was that the number wasn't rounding, i thought it was getting an error message.  yes, indeed, you need to wrap another 'round' around the round() / round() if you want the result rounded (@xQbert).

Comment: Okay, now this is when I get the error in question. I'll add that other round to the question. The error(as stated before) is function round(double precision, integer) does not exist

Comment: Are the inner rounds the right thing to do in the first place? you would get different results in the amounts actually have more than 4 significant digits.  if not, remove them to simplify and see if there's a problem there first.

Comment: @xQbert This error is actually the reason I added the inner rounds in the first place.

Comment: Is there a reason why you round repeatedly? Only increases the error. Should be done once at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I re-formatted your example code to try and understand it more easily:

```
select  round(
            round(
                sum(
                    case
                        when    acct_no = '2999'
                                and date between '1/1/14' and current_date then amount
                    end )::numeric,
                4 )::float
            / round(
                sum(
                    case
                        when    acct_no = '3989'
                                and date between '1/1/14' and current_date then amount
                    end )::numeric,
                4 )::numeric,
            4 ) column
from table
```

The problem is that you're casting the numerator of your division operation as a `float` data type, [which, because you didn't specify a precision, is equivalent to `double precision`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/datatype-numeric.html).

```
round(
    sum(
        case
            when    acct_no = '2999'
                    and date between '1/1/14' and current_date then amount
        end )::numeric,
    4 )::float
/ round(
    sum(
        case
            when    acct_no = '3989'
                    and date between '1/1/14' and current_date then amount
        end )::numeric,
    4 )::numeric
```

So the result of the expression is a `double precision` value instead of as a `numeric` value, hence the error you observed.

Answer (score 6):

```sql
SELECT round((
          sum(CASE WHEN acct_no = '2999' 
              AND thedate between '2014-1-1' AND current_date THEN amount END)
        / sum(CASE WHEN acct_no = '3989' 
              AND thedate between '2014-1-1' AND current_date THEN amount END)
       )::numeric, 4) AS result
FROM   tbl;
```

- There is no function `round()` with added *precision modifier* for floating point types in Postgres. Only for `numeric`, [as per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE).
- Dividing a floating point number by `numeric` results in `double precision` (`float8`). Test:

  ```
    SELECT 5::float/3::numeric  -- result is double precision
  ```
- Round *once* at the end of your calculation. That's faster and more accurate.
- Never use `date` as column name. It's a reserved word in standard SQL and a base type in Postgres.
- It's best to use the [recommended ISO 8601 date format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE) in date literals in your code. This works irregardless of settings and locale, while your local format would break with different settings.

If it wasn't for the `rest of the query` you mentioned, this could be simplified further:

```sql
SELECT round((   sum(CASE WHEN acct_no = '2999' THEN amount END)
        / NULLIF(sum(CASE WHEN acct_no = '3989' THEN amount END), 0)
       )::numeric, 4) AS result
FROM   tbl
WHERE  thedate between '2014-1-1'::date AND current_date;
```

Finally, this also catches "division by 0" exceptions using `NULLIF()` on the divisor.